# Possible? Record play counts for embedded YouTube videos

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, youtube, youtube-api, soundcloud

I have a webapp that allows users to post videos. I was wondering if it would be possible to record the play counts so that each time someone clicks the play button a counter adds +1.

I'm currently using auto_html to do the embedding:

```
   <% if micropost.url.include? 'youtu' %>
      <%= auto_html(micropost.url) {youtube(:width => 550, :height => 190)}   %>
   <% end %>

   <% if micropost.url.include? 'soundcloud' %>
     <%= auto_html(micropost.url) {soundcloud}  %>
   <% end %>
```

For Youtube it would have to record when I click anywhere on the embedded video and for Soundcloud it would have to a play once the play button is clicked. How could this be done? Greatly appreciate input.

I do not want the video's youtube view count, I want to know how many times someone on my website views it.

Comment: Youtube analytics?  http://www.youtube.com/yt/advertise/youtube-analytics.html.  There is an experimental API here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/

Answer (score 2):

. . The [YouTube API ("video entry")](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Retrieve_video_entry) gives you this information in a more reliable way, so you don't need to store it yourself. Just get "entry->yt:statistics->viewCount" information.

. . It's worth noticing that the "viewCount" will not increment when you *start* playing the video, but rather after some time. I can't remember exactly how much, but I think it's when you watch some 75% of the video or something.

. . **EDIT** just putting it here so anyone that gets through google will get it.

. . If you need to save it on your server for some reason, you can use the [Youtube JavaScript API to get a event fired](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Events) when the video starts to play (check the "onStateChange" event for a value of "1"--when the video starts to actually play). SoundCloud also have a [Widget API event for that: "onMediaStart"](https://github.com/soundcloud/Widget-JS-API/wiki#wiki-widget-events).

. . You can then make some Ajax call to save the info on your server.

```
var MEDIA_ID = 1; //your internal's media ID;
function checkPlayerState(newState) { if (newState === 1) { incrementCount(); } }
function incrementCount() { $.post('inc.php', {mediaid: MEDIA_ID}); }

soundcloud.addEventListener('onMediaStart', incrementCount);
ytplayer.addEventListener('onStateChange', checkPlayerState);
```

Comment: I don't want to know how many views the video has on youtube. I want to know how many times a user plays the video on another user's page my website. So yes I want to record the information...

Comment: In this case, you need to use the JavaScript API to get a event fired when the video starts to play (check the "onStateChange" event for a value of "1"--when the video starts to actually play). You can then make some Ajax call to save the info on your server.

Comment: For SoundCloud you have [something alike on their API](https://github.com/soundcloud/Widget-JS-API/wiki#wiki-widget-events): "onMediaStart"